# WiFi ping spikes after disconnecting from wired network

Tags: network, wifi

I have been experiencing spikes of high latency on my WiFi (100-200ms) on my MacBook Pro M1, though I have experienced the same on my previous machine, a MacBook Pro (2020) Intel i5. I have seen a number of posts here revolving around location services and I have gone through all the troubleshooting I could find, including completely shutting off location services. As part of those troubleshooting steps, I have tried to enable WiFi logging, which unfortunately does not seem to capture anything to /var/log/wifi.log.

By complete accident, I discovered that rebooting solves the issue until I connect to my Thunderbolt 4 dock, which has a wired network connection. Upon unplugging from the dock, the latency spikes over WiFi return and will persist until I reboot. Disconnecting and reconnecting to WiFi, or disabling and re-enabling WiFi does not resolve the issue; the *only* thing I can find to fix it is a full reboot.

I have confirmed this also happens if I connect with a USB-C Ethernet adapter. I also believe this was happening on my previous Intel MacBook Pro, as I'd occasionally get these latency spikes, but that was before I had the dock and would only use a wired connection when transferring large files; I can't confirm it was the same cause.

As part of my troubleshooting I've upgraded the wireless access point since I had plans to do that anyway, and I get the same issue.

What could cause connecting (or disconnecting) to a wired network to start interfering with my WiFi?

EDIT: Adding Ping results

I rebooted the machine disconnected from the dock. After it reconnected to WiFi, I pinged the router on 172.21.1.1:

```
PING 172.21.1.1 (172.21.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=7.735 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=10.255 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=10.375 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=7.493 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=16.935 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=9.610 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=5.452 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=7.797 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=9.358 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=8.008 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=6.562 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=8.209 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=3.574 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=9.258 ms
```

This pinged similarly for over a minute.

Then I connected the dock, made sure it established connection over the wired connection, then disconnected the dock again and ran the same ping test:

```
PING 172.21.1.1 (172.21.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=248.706 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=162.579 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.871 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=8.157 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=10.389 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=31.223 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=4.336 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=5.454 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=4.326 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=4.864 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=49.365 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=100.922 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=136.984 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=181.316 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=226.021 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=5.319 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=5.056 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=29.611 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=73.903 ms
```

Comment: Do you have sample ping results we can evaluate?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the post to include ping results.

Comment: Your results are likely from the change in routing table with a mukti-homed node having more than one unique network interfaces. In other words, adding and deleting the Ethernet interface requires routing changes to be made and this can cause momentary latency issues. This is not a concern here.

Comment: Run the ping for several minutes and you should be able to quickly see if the latency die down over a relatively short time.

Comment: I left it pinging while I ran out for some errands and after 2 hours I was still getting these random spikes.

64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=10117 ttl=64 time=6.855 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=10118 ttl=64 time=6.380 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=10119 ttl=64 time=10.512 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=10120 ttl=64 time=5.720 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=10121 ttl=64 time=91.639 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=10122 ttl=64 time=137.200 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.1.1: icmp_seq=10123 ttl=64 time=27.555 ms